# Is there any way to change background and default frame of popover View loaded using UIPopoverViewController?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, calayer, uipopovercontroller

(1) Trying change the frame color of popover Background but its not happening... Is there any way to change it?

(2) Have tried removing the sublayer of popover and replacing with other layer with this was able to remove the default frame but the application crashes while dissmising the popover.

(3) Is there any way to hide a layer and changing background color to clearColor?
`layer.hidden=yes;` is not working.

```
layer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor] 
// is not working but its working for other colors like blueColor
```